# JavaScript and jquery not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I did a web app with some JavaScript and jQuery which works well on PC but on mobile those functions do not work.

Functions like creating a table row dynamically at clicking a button using :

```
      var table = document.getElementById("table");
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);
```

also my ajax call is not working on mobile, below is some major part of the function (creating table row and ajax call)

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getProduct',
    data: { product_id:product_id },
    dataType : 'json',
    success:function(response){

      var name = response.products['name'];
      var id =  response.products['id'];
      var bid = document.getElementById('buyer_id').value;
      var sid = <?php echo $this->session->userdata('id'); ?>;
      var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
      var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
      if(category=='agent'){
        var price =  response.products['agent_price'];
      }else{
        var price =  response.products['vendor_price'];
      }

      var table = document.getElementById("table");
      var row = table.insertRow(-1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1); 
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(-1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(-1);
      var cell4 = row.insertCell(-1);
      var cell5 = row.insertCell(-1);
      cell1.innerHTML = count;
      cell2.innerHTML = name;
      cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="quantity[]" onblur="addamount()" />';
      cell4.innerHTML = price;
      cell4.id=count;
      cell5.innerHTML = '<a href="#" class="remove btn btn-danger btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete</a>';
    }

});
```

Comment: are your jquery files included in the app? or are they hosted on some CDN somewhere?

Comment: self hosted am using jquery-2.0.3.min.js

Comment: what kind of app is it? is jquery deployed with it?

Comment: @JanR no its a php app just using js functions to make it dynamic

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? Also are you using the 'click' event to trigger the code? Maybe try using 'touchstart' instead

Comment: its working on computer as expected just on mobile and on computer there is no console error also the function is being ran by using onclick="myFunction()" on the button maybe i should try addEventListener()

Comment: Theres a lot of silliness happening with how you are trying to inject dom objects.

Comment: I think the click event is not firing on mobile. Try creating the addEventListener for touchstart

Comment: @BrandtSolovij that didnt help at all, yes im new to js and might have approached this the wrong way but you can only help point me to the right path. this is how i am using the function. when the button is clicked the function is ran and a row is being created with some variables, you might not understand it as the above is not my whole script

Comment: my apologies-there are numerous holes in this question: what is `var sid = <?php echo $this->session->userdata('id'); ?>;` ? does it return what is expected? you're also commingling jquery objects with elements and nodes. InnerHTML is additionally costly here. Theres a lot going on that makes this poor performing. If you are interested in using jquery(and mobile) - perhaps take a look at the docs and better conform to those standards. And Finally : is the json response what you expect? I dont know, you didnt share it.

Comment: $this->session->userdata('id') is returning an id which is working fine

Comment: For starters, avoid 'onClick'. Use jQuery's ['on'](http://api.jquery.com/on) function on your html element.

From there on, include an 'error' function to your $.ajax, to catch the error (if there is any).

Finally, if all of this isn't working. A simple `$(function(){alert('jqueryisrunningwoohoo'};` code in your page can check if jquery is being loaded

Comment: @Mysteryos thanks just tried all that and it happened that Jquery is not being loaded on mobile. what do you think?

Comment: @user2666633 try using a CDN, such as https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide